# How to handle a ListView ItemCheck Event from another Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I create a ListView Control in my `Form2` at run-time. In `Form3` I have a `ListView.ItemCheck` Event (code is added below).
Unfortunately, I do not have access to `Form2`. This could be remedies, if I add the code on `Form2`, but i want to handle the `ListView ItemCheck` Event from `Form3`.

How can this be solved?

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    private Form2 parentForm;

    public Form3(Form2 parentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.parentForm = parentForm;

        this.parentForm.listView1.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(ListView1_ItemCheck);
    }
   
    private void ListView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parentForm.listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != e.Index)
                {
                    if (parentForm.listView1.Items[i].Checked == true)
                    {
                        parentForm.listView1.Items[i].Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Pass the instance of your ListView instead of a Form instance.

Comment: It is difficult to understand “what” you are trying to do and it makes no sense to me. You state that… _”i want to handle the ListView ItemCheck Event from Form3.”_ …? … WHY? … The ONLY way the event will fire is if `Form2` is the “active” form. In other words, the user can not “check/uncheck” a list item in `Form2` from `Form3`. Can you explain WHY you want `Form3` to capture the event from `Form2`? I am just saying this is very odd and you need to explain exactly what you are trying to do. What is the relationship between `Form3` and the `ListView` on `Form2`?

Comment: In addition, you should be aware that when the event is fired and execution gets to the line… `parentForm.listView1.Items[i].Checked = false;` … then this is going to RE-Fire the event. It may still work; however the code is calling the event many more times than is needed. It may be easier if you elaborate a little more on ”WHAT” you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, „JohnG“ for your detailed replies. I was not really conscious about that, what the ItemCheck Event really means. I always thought that, especially the ItemCheck Event on Form3 could capture the event on From2. That was just one reflection, nothing more. However, luckily i was taught there of a better one : ) Thank you for doing that and for your support!!!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, "Jimi". Unfortunately, however, that is not possible (see JohnG’s reply)

Comment: Hmmm… Please let me clarify… From your last comment… _”Unfortunately, however, that is not possible”_ … well… this is not true… it IS possible, it depends on what you want to do. Your current code will work, however the `Form2` event is in `Form3`… if `Form3` is NOT open… then the event will NOT fire. Does this mean you ONLY want the event to fire if `Form3` is open? This is where it is confusing as to “why” you want `Form2`’s event in `Form3`.

Comment: IF you wanted `Form3` to DO something IN `Form3` when the event fires in `Form2`… then you have this backwards. You would make some “public” methods in `Form3` that you could call from `Form2` and call those methods from the `Form2` event. However, in this example… the code in the event is “specific” to `Form2` and more specifically with the `ListView` on `Form2` so it is hard to see what `Form3` would do when the event in `Form2` is fired. Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: There is no need to worry.You helped me a lot!!. That’s correct. I want the event to fire if Form3 is open. I have drawn up a gif. Maybe, this could provide a comprehensive picture of the ItemCheck Event problem. On this Form2 there is a ListView and a TextBox. I would like to checkmark the checkboxes 3 and 5 from the Form3 event (see the gif above)

Comment: Please forgive me, I am just not getting where `Form3` comes into the picture. The gif shows the list view and a text box on `Form2`, when the user clicks on a list view check box, it appears that only “Book 3” and ”Book 5” are placed into the text box when either one is clicked. You state that… _”I would like to checkmark the checkboxes 3 and 5 from the Form3 event”_ ? … So in `Form3`, you want to check the check boxes 3 and 5 in `Form2` from `Form3`… OK… WHEN would you want to do this in `Form3`?

Comment: In other words what would trigger this in `Form3`? What would happen in `Form3` that would be the trigger to check the check boxes in the list box items 3 and 5 in `Form2`? This is very strange; I am just not understanding where `Form3` comes into this picture. SOMETHING has to happen IN `FORM3` to trigger this setting of the list box values in `Form2`. Having it triggered from `From2` in `Form3` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @mike19,if you want something to happen when form3 opens, then do it from within the form3 load event. Have you tried that?

Comment: There must be a basic error of reasoning in my approach. You are absolutely right, triggering from From2 in Form3 makes absolutely no sense!! I’m astonished, that i had previously failed to notice. As the phrase goes: Among the blind the one-eyed is king ; ) I apologize for the inconvencience this may caused you. Many thanks once again for all your efforts, JohnG!

Comment: You are right. I will do it, David. Thanks for the tip!